# Revertir salida de print_r a su array original en PHP

Tags: php, array

Esta pregunta la hago debido a una dificultad que encuentro sobre todo respondiendo a preguntas aquí mismo.

Cuando se comparte el resultado del `print_r` de un array, por ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dim1] => Array
                (
                    [dim1.1] => valor1.1
                    [dim1.2] => valor1.2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dim2] => Array
                (
                    [dim2.1] => valor2.1
                    [dim2.2] => valor2.2
                    [dim2.3] => valor2.3
                )

        )

)
```

Interesa tener el array original, por ejemplo para hacer pruebas de código.

**¿Existe alguna función propia de PHP para revertir desde un `print_r` el array original sin importar la estructura o las dimensiones del array?**

**¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?**

Por ejemplo:

El resultado que se quiere obtener a partir del `print_r` indicado más arriba sería una variable como esta:

```
$array=array(
                array("dim1"=>array ("dim1.1"=>"valor1.1", "dim1.2"=>"valor1.2")), 
                array("dim2"=>array ("dim2.1"=>"valor2.1", "dim2.2"=>"valor2.2", "dim2.3"=>"valor2.3"))
            );
```

> Pero, se trata de encontrar una función **que convierta cualquier
>   salida de `print_r` a su array original**.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Existe alguna función propia de PHP para revertir desde un print_r el array original sin importar la estructura o las dimensiones del array?

Yo al menos no la conozco.

> ¿Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Este código lo he encontrado en el [manual de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php#93529) escrito por **Matt**. Se puede ver funcionando en [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6ac2b0aa7910e90dbf34a3b43443d8c6630e441).

```
function print_r_reverse($in) { 
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($in)); 
    if (trim($lines[0]) != 'Array') { 
        // bottomed out to something that isn't an array 
        return $in; 
    } else { 
        // this is an array, lets parse it 
        if (preg_match("/(\s{5,})\(/", $lines[1], $match)) { 
            // this is a tested array/recursive call to this function 
            // take a set of spaces off the beginning 
            $spaces = $match[1]; 
            $spaces_length = strlen($spaces); 
            $lines_total = count($lines); 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_total; $i++) { 
                if (substr($lines[$i], 0, $spaces_length) == $spaces) { 
                    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], $spaces_length); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        array_shift($lines); // Array 
        array_shift($lines); // ( 
        array_pop($lines); // ) 
        $in = implode("\n", $lines); 
        // make sure we only match stuff with 4 preceding spaces (stuff for this array and not a nested one) 
        preg_match_all("/^\s{4}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER); 
        $pos = array(); 
        $previous_key = ''; 
        $in_length = strlen($in); 
        // store the following in $pos: 
        // array with key = key of the parsed array's item 
        // value = array(start position in $in, $end position in $in) 
        foreach ($matches as $match) { 
            $key = $match[1][0]; 
            $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]); 
            $pos[$key] = array($start, $in_length); 
            if ($previous_key != '') $pos[$previous_key][1] = $match[0][1] - 1; 
            $previous_key = $key; 
        } 
        $ret = array(); 
        foreach ($pos as $key => $where) { 
            // recursively see if the parsed out value is an array too 
            $ret[$key] = print_r_reverse(substr($in, $where[0], $where[1] - $where[0])); 
        } 
        return $ret; 
    } 
}

$print = "Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dim1] => Array
                (
                    [dim1.1] => valor1.1
                    [dim1.2] => valor1.2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dim2] => Array
                (
                    [dim2.1] => valor2.1
                    [dim2.2] => valor2.2
                    [dim2.3] => valor2.3
                )

        )

)";

$result = print_r_reverse($print);

var_dump($result);
```

> No lo he probado a fondo, pero el ejemplo que has indicado lo resuelve correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso esta web

[convert-print-r-to-php-array](https://wtools.io/convert-print-r-to-php-array)

Pero si necesitas convertirlo dentro de un flujo, si debes utilizar la función dejada por OscarR

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/343654)